# Cocoa's NIB/XIB Confusion

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

Just a newbie with iPhone development.. I just have a small problem but huge confusion with regards to NIB files. In Cocoa, how can we change the File's owner and First responder of a nib? And BTW, when can we actually say that we need more than one NIB file for a project in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the class of File's owner in Interface builder (select File's owner and open Identity inspector). You don't need to change anything in First responder.
As to your second question - you can build an entire project programmatically without nibs. I build mine with nibs for every view, controller, custom control etc.

Comment: thanks.. but how and why do you need one nib for each view, controller?

Comment: When I create views programmatically, I use nibs for defining some initial (default) state for view/control instead of writing pages of code to set it up.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open the nib, click on "File's Owner"
2. Select the third inspection tool, "Identity Inspector" (?)
3. Type in the class this nib needs to be associated with.

[image]